# Conditional PDF of sum of three random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are three random variables with the following relation x+y+z=1000, given z, what is the pdf of x+y.

I would like to know the general approach to this question. But for example we can assume that they are uniformly distributed in 0 to 1000

Comment: Given the relation $X+Y+Z=1000$ and $Z$, $X+Y$ is a deterministic random variable, you surely meant something else, e.g. the pdf of $X$ ($X$ in this case is conditionally uniform on $[0,1000-Z]$).

Comment: @Olivier yes, but wouldn't X be uniformly distributed in [-z, 1000 - z], since X=1000-z-y and Y ranges from 0 to 1000

Comment: According to your assumptions, the marginal of X would be the uniform distribution om [0,1000]. Conditioned on any kind of event cannot make this random variable take negative values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
W = X+Y = 1000-Z &\Rightarrow \text{ c.d.f. of }W \text{ is } \\
F_W(w) &= P(W \leq w) = P(1000-Z \leq w) = \\
&= P(Z \geq 1000-w) = 1-F_Z(1000-w), \\
\text{where }F_Z(\cdot)&\text{ is a c.d.f. of }Z \Rightarrow \\
&\Rightarrow f_W(w) = (1-F_Z(1000-w))' = 1'-F'_Z(1000-w)\cdot(1000-w)' = \\
&= f_Z(1000-w), \\
\text{where }f_Z(\cdot)&\text{ is a p.d.f. of }Z
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: thanks for the answer and as an extension can we now figure out the pdf of X given we observe Y after the initial event of observing Z?

Comment: @Dspguysam $F_Z(1000-w)=P(Z\leq 1000-w)$. So, $$\begin{align}1-F_Z(1000-w)&=1-P(Z\leq 1000-w)\\&=P(1000-w>Z)\\&=P(1000-w\leq Z)-\mathbf{P(1000-w=Z)}\end{align}$$ The latter term $P(1000-w=Z)$ could be non-zero for some random variables.

Comment: @Quarantino i didn't quite get the final point you wanted to make regarding the non zero probability of the last term, are you hinting at some violation?

Comment: @Dspguysam Yes, it means that the last equation in the first displayed formula, in this answer is not correct, in general. It is true, for example, when the random variables are continuous random variables. For continuous random variables the probability of getting a particular value is $0$. So, the term $P(1000-w=Z)$ would be zero. For other types of random variables this need not be true.